# Azure websites with SSL on custom domains

Tags: azure

I have a custom domain customdomain.com

I have the following in the domain's DNS:
A Record:
emea
Pointing to the IP indicated in the "domain names" section of the Azure websites configuration pane.

C-Name Record:
awverify.emea   awverify.azurewebsite.azurewebsites.net

I can add emea.customdomain.com in Azure's configuration, so I guess verification is OK.

I have uploaded a SSL wildcard certicate for *.customdomain.com
In the certificates section, the cerficate is visible with the expiration date:
*.customdomain.com,customdomain.com

In SSL bindings I've coupled the certificate with the domain:

emea.customdomain.com

CN=PositiveSSL CA 2, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB, Expires: 5-9-2013

SNI SSL

When I type in https://emea.customdomain.com, the browser tells me the site I'm referring to is presenting itself as *.azurewebsites.net so the SSL connection cannot be established.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the certificate itself was wrong.

I received a crt certificate which I had to convert to pfx. I neglected to supply a private key with that. The pfx was constructed without private key. Azure doesn't complain about it, but it just doesn't work.

I recommend using openssl to generate the csr (certificate request), not IIS. With openssl, a separate private key file generated which you can then include in the pfx.

To construct the csr:

```
openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
```

To create the pfx:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```